# How to make a Bootstrap navbar that has menu separated menu items

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

So by default a Bootstrap menu navbar goes like this:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

But I need to make each menu item separated from each other so the final image would be looked like this:

[image]

So how can I make Bootstrap `nav-item` separated from each other?

I would really appreciate any idea or suggestion from you guys...

**UPDATE:**

I tried this code, but didn't solve the problem:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active bg-warning m-2">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item bg-warning m-2">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item bg-warning m-2">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item bg-warning m-2">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add `background` `bg-warning` to all `nav-item`s and giving `margin`s to separate them

```
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active bg-warning m-2">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item bg-warning m-2">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item bg-warning m-2">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item bg-warning m-2">
                <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: But you didn't specify margin in your code

Comment: I tried `.nav-item{ margin-right:5px; }` but didn't work

Comment: `m-2`  is a bootstrap class for `margin`s

Comment: I just added an **UPDATE** about the result that I got from testing your code

Comment: https://codepen.io/junaidcody/pen/BawJKvM

Comment: what code do you have above `nav` ?